# log return calculation by many companies r

Tags: r, logging, return, stock, ln

I have a file like this.

```
head(Historical_Stock_Prices_R)
    Date1     MSFT    AAPL   GOOGL
1 25-01-05 21.02985 4.873362 88.56
2 26-01-05 21.02177 4.886890 94.62
3 27-01-05 21.10259 4.913269 94.04
```

want to calculate log return using this formula ln(current price/previous price) and my expected output is like this

```
 Date1        MSFT   AAPL    GOOGL          
26-01-05    -0.04%  0.28%    6.62%
27-01-05     0.38%  0.54%   -0.61%
```

tried to solve by this codes from previous stack overflow answer but fail

```
logs=data.frame( cbind.data.frame(newdates[-1], 

diff(as.matrix(log(Historical_Stock_Prices_R[,-1])))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = read.table(text="
Date1     MSFT    AAPL   GOOGL
1 25-01-05 21.02985 4.873362 88.56
2 26-01-05 21.02177 4.886890 94.62
3 27-01-05 21.10259 4.913269 94.04",header=T)

cbind.data.frame(date=df$Date1[-1],apply(df[,2:4],2,function(x) log(x[-1]/x[-length(x)])*100))

#       date        MSFT      AAPL      GOOGL
# 2 26-01-05 -0.03842896 0.2772061  6.6188582
# 3 27-01-05  0.38372143 0.5383395 -0.6148647
```

Comment: After giving this code  cbind.data.frame(date=Historical_Stock_Prices_R$Date1[2:3],apply(Historical_Stock_Prices_R[,2:4],2,function(x) log(x[-1]/x[-length(x)])*100))
it shows this      Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 2245
>

Comment: My bad, that would be because I used your example (2 rows) and your matrix is presumably larger. I replaced `df$Date1[2:nrow(df)]` which should do the trick. (mind that df = Historical_Stock_Prices_R)

Comment: sorry I understand

Comment: cbind.data.frame(date=df$Date1[2:nrow(df)],apply(df[,2:4],2,function(x) log(x[-1]/x[-length(x)])*100))
Error in df$Date1 : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: np :) You could replace `paste0(round(log(x[-1]/x[-length(x)])*100,digits=2),"%")` to get your desired output incl. 2 dec points and the `%` sign

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could be a bit more precise as to what you mean with "fail". Add your error message for example. See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on good questions

In any case I suspect that if you replace your code with the following it should work.

```
logs=data.frame( cbind.data.frame(Historical_Stock_Prices_R["Date1",-1], diff(as.matrix(log(Historical_Stock_Prices_R[,-1])))))
```

The reason your code fails is that there probably is no object in your environment called "newdates", so you have to refer to the original dataframe.
You can then rename the column afterwards.

Comment: it partially working. Giving an warning message of this

Comment: In data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :
  row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded

Comment: output is like this

Comment: NA NA NA and than the values

Answer (score 0):

Using TTR package and ROC

```
> library(TTR)
> stocks
     Date1     MSFT     AAPL GOOGL
1 25-01-05 21.02985 4.873362 88.56
2 26-01-05 21.02177 4.886890 94.62
3 27-01-05 21.10259 4.913269 94.04


> rocMSFT <- ROC(stocks[,"MSFT"])
> rocMSFT
[1]            NA -0.0003842896  0.0038372143
```

but also look at dailyReturn: calculate daily returns from quantmod
http://www.quantmod.com/documentation/periodReturn.html